# how to deserialize an array of data?

Tags: javascript, ajax

please help to bring the console dataset.

I do Ajax request and receive a response date as an array:

```
[{"pk": 2, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile", "fields": {"phone": "21", "other": "<p>qqqqqqdfgdfg</p><p><b>fdg</b></p>", "user_permissions": [], "avatar": "", "skype": "dfsdf", "gender": 2, "groups": []}}]
```

the problem is that the console does not work and bring

```
data.pk
```

and

```
data.model
```

screenshot [here](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=faec8750656865aea3e5e8ad635959a8)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/search_author/",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    data: {
        "author": $('#formSearchAuthorWord').val(),
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $.csrf_token
    },
    success: function(data) {   
        console.log(data)           
        console.log(data.pk)            
        console.log(data.model)                         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's inside the array.. access them like:

```
data[0].pk
data[0].model
```

"[]" brackets represents an array and "{}" an object.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/yqbur15f/)**